# Proguard query, which one is being used

Tags: android, proguard

My android project is has a file called **project.properties** and i've enabled Proguard by uncommenting the line that says **proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt**.

I also have another file called **proguard-project.txt**. I'm using **BugSense* in my app so I have put **-keep class com.bugsense** etc etc in it.

My question is, which proguard properties are actually used? Because there are two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you activate proguard using the code **proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt**, the rules defined in **proguard-project.txt** is just uppended to the rules defined in **/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt**

Comment: So my bugsense wont get obfuscated?

Comment: ofcourse it will get obfuscated with respect to the rules defined by you.

Comment: keep class is used to flag the builder to exclude those classes from being obfuscated.